# Docker error while creating mount source path

Tags: docker, nginx

I’m trying to create nginx container with mounted volume in */var/www*:

```
docker run --name nginx-app1 -v /var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 11080:80 nginx
```

And I get the error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source
> path '/var /www': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system.

I also tried to run it with sudo, but is the same error. When I try to mount the volume in */home/username/* everything is fine.

The */var/www* dir have drwxr-xr-x permissions. I working with Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker 20.10.11

Any suggestions on what might be causing the problem?

Comment: *The /var/www dir have drwxr-xr-x permissions.* --- do you mean your host, or the filesystem with in docker(check it by exec into, and not mounting volume)?

Comment: What's the output of `grep /var/www /proc/self/mountinfo`?

Comment: @LeiYang These are the permissions on the host. The container has been created, but I cannot start them (when I try to run it, I get an error)

Comment: do you mean woking when you use `-v /home/username/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro`?

Comment: @JeffRSon I am trying to run it, but I have nothing in the output

Comment: okay, then just `grep /var /proc/self/mountinfo`

Comment: @JeffRSon  Again, nothing on the output

Comment: Interesting - so post the output of `findmnt`.